# Sending random number to email PHP

Tags: php, email, random

i am trying to send a random number to an email but unable to this is the code that i have been able to come up with so far 
please help if possible

**sendmail.php**

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
$header ='From:admin@domain.com';
$subject ='Verification Code';  

    if(empty($to))
        {
            echo "Email is Empty";
        }
        else
        {
            if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)){

             echo 'Check Your Email FOr verfication code';
            }
            else{
                echo 'Failed';
            } 
        }
```

index.php

```
<form action = "register.php" method="POST">

<p>Username</p>
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="40" value='<?php if(isset($username)) echo $username ?>'"><br>

<p>New Password</p>
<input type="password" name="password"> 

 <p>email</p>
<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="40" value='<?php if(isset($email)) echo $email ?>'"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register"> <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Answer (score 2):

**In form(*index.php*)**

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
    <lable>email</lable>>
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="40">
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Register"> 

</form>
```

**In sendmail.php**

```
$rand= rand(10, 20)// random number generator
$to = $_POST['email'];
$header ='From:admin@domain.com';
$subject ='Verification Code';

$message = "Your Random number is";
$message .= $rand;
$message .= "Thank you-Admin";

if(empty($to))
{
    echo "Email is Empty";
}
else
{
    if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)){

     echo 'Check Your Email FOr verfication code';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Failed';
    } 
}
```

Comment: oopz sory.  add this in form  `method="post"`

Comment: i have edited my question with proper details i still get an error of email empty

Comment: remove `value` part in `<input>`

Comment: i am still getting the error email empty
after doing this
'<input type="text" name="email"> <br>'

Comment: i think the problem is iam unable to fetch the email from
index.php to sendmail.php

Comment: is there file call **sendmail.php**

Comment: yes but with a different name
funny thing is when i switch the
 $to='myemail';
it works
so what are your views sir

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add semicolon at the end of first line

```
$rand= mt_rand(100000, 999999)
```

It should be

```
$rand= mt_rand(100000, 999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the hosting service that You're using does not accept sending using mail() functions. Maybe for security reasons to prevent virus-like php scripts to send spams from Your account.
So create admin@domain.com email account and using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) send Your email:

```
require __DIR__.'/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                    
$mail->Host = 'smtp.hostname.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;             
$mail->Username = 'no-reply@domain.com';                 
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;    
$mail->setFrom('admin@domain.com');
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->isHTML(true);   
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $body;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

- download link and examples here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: it does i was able to send a email by specifying stuffs directly

Comment: You know, I had site in shared hosting too and one day mail() stopped working too. Solution was using phpmailer, try it, will see at least the $mail->ErrorInfo  at least (: